# Finish entering text in GPG

Tags: terminal, gpg

If you call GPG without input, it just says

```
gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

You can enter text and everything, but how do you end the input? I've seen something like this in multiple different programs, but I've never known how.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to input EOF (End Of File). Do this with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or more generally, `^D`).

Comment: Thanks! I had tried a number of things, including _typing_ EOF.

Comment: Also, is there a way to delete a newline in this input? As in, having pressed Enter, doing a "backspace" as you would in a regular editor?

Comment: @IBPX I don't think it is possible to delete new lines in this situation. However, I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @tchen No, it is not possible. This is because pressing return causes what you've typed so far to be flushed into the input buffer of the program (or file, or whatever keyboard input happens to be connected to)—once that happens, it's likely that the program is already operating on it (or that it's already being written to the file, or…), so there isn't an easy way to undo it.

Comment: @tchen Fun fact: pressing control-d actually also flushes input in the same way. Pressing it when you've just flushed (either with control-d or with return) still flushes, only it flushes _zero bytes_ (making the `read()` system call return `0`), which is how the system communicates that the end of a file has been reached. Sometimes (usually not, but sometimes!), a program will keep reading even after it's gotten the end-of-file indication. Off the top of my head, `gnutls-cli` does this when you pass `--starttls`.

Comment: Anyway, I find typing directly into a file or a program's stdin mostly useful for testing things and other cases when mistakes don't matter or I'm not likely to make a mistake spanning multiple lines. If you need to do any kind of composition beyond that, you'd be better served by the editor of your choice.

Comment: @BlacklightShining I see. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I suspect, @IBPX that your real question is, how do you get EOF to end the input, without putting a newline first? Because that's my real question... In which case, to summarize Blacklight -- **just press CTRL-D twice**........ (why didn't I think of that?)

Answer (score 1):

Without any flags, gpg assumes you want to decrypt, expects an encrypted message, and will output the results, in binary, to stdout.

If you want to encrypt something and deal with the result in a practical way, try `gpg -ea` and then type some secret message, then cntrl-d and give recipients, when asked.

You can then copy the ascii-armored message to the clipboard which you can paste into a file or whatever.

If you relauch gpg without flags and paste that message in, it will ask for recipient's key passphrase, and then wait for you to close stdin... type ctrl-d and your message will be decrypted to stdout

Comment: Do you know a practical use-case for typing out an already encrypted message into GPG like that? I'm confused why it wouldn't expect unencrypted stuff to encrypt instead.

Comment: It just defaults to decrypting with no flags whether you specify a file or not. WRT use-case for typing an encrypted message, if all you have is paper then typing is all you have; but pasting, yes: sharing encrypted files via electronic means like email is simpler, particularly on the receiver end, using ascii-armored files.
There was a day when you HAD to do that; otherwise, one bit of each byte of your binary file would have been stripped, because the Internet at that time assumed everything being communicated was encoded as (the original) ASCII text which was only represented by 7 bits.